# Find and replace in a protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to perform *'Find and Replace'* in a protected sheet? I tried, but it prompts an error

> ***"You cannot use this command on a protected sheet. To use this command, you must first unprotect the worksheet (Review tab, changes
>   groups, unprotect sheet button) You may be prompted for a password"***

I need to find some words to be replaced with other words, but at the same time I want the sheet to be protected. Is that possible? Or is there any VBA way to solve this?

Comment: Are you doing the Find and Replace manually or using VBA?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Yeah, I do it manually. I also applied VBA code for some specific words that I need to be replace with, and it's worked. But in the same time, I also want the user to have their own word to be replaced. In that case, I need to enable 'Find and Replace' feature to allow them replacing word which they want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use VBA, you can unprotect and then protect it again via vba code.

```
Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").Unprotect Password:="YourPW"
FindAndReplace
Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").Protect Password:="YourPW"
```

The `Unprotect` and `Protect` methods have many more arguments for more granular control. [Look here for more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel)
To replace your values, you can use a combination of `Find` and `Replace` but there are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use macros you may have to unprotect the sheets before performing any manipulation operations. You can do that with the macro & you can put the protection back on before the macro closes.
2. Set the Options to Look in Values

What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: As you probably know by now, you need to unprotect the sheet, do the work, and then re-protect the sheet.  A small VBA script will do the job for you and you can easily Google this.

Comment: I didn't find "Look in Values" in Replace options. It only allow me to look in formulas. Why was that? I'm using Microsoft Excel 2013 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Worksheet(1).Protect Password:="YourPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

That will allow the macro to run even when it is protected.